# $J'$ is a fractional ideal, then multiplying by principal ideal does not change class. So one can assume $J^{-1}$ is integral ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This is a part of proof given in Pierre Samuel's Algebraic Theory of Numbers which I do not understand why it can be done in this way.

Let $K$ be a number field. Let $A$ be integral closure of $Z$ in $K$. Denote the set of all non-zero fractional ideals as $I(A)$ and non-zero principal fractional ideals as $F(A)$. The ideal class group is denoted as $I(A)/F(A)$.

Let $J'\in I(A)/F(A)$. It is clear that multiplying by a principal ideal of $A$ does not change class. We can assume without loss of generality $J=(J')^{-1}$ is integral ideal($J\subset A$).

Q: Why can I assume $J=(J')^{-1}$ is an integral ideal(i.e $J\subset A$) by multiplying $J'$ by some principal ideal?

If $b\in A, b(J')^{-1}\subset A$, then I consider $(b(J')^{-1})^{-1}=J'(\frac{1}{b})$. There is no guarantee that $\frac{1}{b}\in A$.

Comment: $J^{-1}$ doesn't have the same meaning in the ideal class group $C_K$ and in the fractional ideal group $I_K$. The ideal class group is the quotient $C_K = I_K/P_K$ where $P_K= K^* / O_K^\times$ is the principal fractional ideal group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{b}$ is not in $A$ unless $b$ is a unit, in which case $(J')^{-1}$ is already integral. But to more directly answer your question, $(\frac{1}{b})$ is not a principal ideal of $A$, but it is a principal **fractional** ideal of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I' \in I(A)$ be a lift of $J'$, and let $I$ be an integral ideal lift of $(J')^{-1}$, say $I = b(I')^{-1}$. It follows that $II' = bA$ is principal, so $I$ and $I'$ represent inverse elements of the ideal class group.

Note that it does *not* follow, however, that $I^{-1} \subset A$. The assumption only says $I \subset A$. It is true that, in the ideal class group, $I^{-1}$ could be represented by an integral ideal (e.g., if we assumed WLOG that $I'$ was integral, then $I'$ would be such a representative), but $I^{-1}$ itself is not typically such a representative.

In fact it's not too difficult to show that if $I, I^{-1}$ are both integral ideals, then $I = I^{-1} = A$.